# Process synchronization with signals

Tags: c, concurrency, synchronization, signals, fork

Nowadays, I'm learning signals by own efforts with concurrency. However, I have some problems while using them in action. In this program, I expect that there are two processes (one child - one parent), parent sends `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTSTP` signals to its child respectively. I want the child to handle them in same order. I'm trying to apply synchronization with signals here. I have two major problems that

- When parent runs at first prior its child, it works but it misses
  `SIGINT`, not go into its handler.
- When child runs at first prior its parent, it blocks. I expect in
  either way the program runs well.

I really appreciate as well if you let me inform the other issues and their solutions along with the major ones'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char const * hupMsg = "CHILD: I have received a SIGHUP\n";
int hupMsgLen;
void sighup(int x) {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, hupMsg, hupMsgLen);

}

char const * intMsg = "CHILD: I have received a SIGINT\n";
int intMsgLen;
void sigint(int x) {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, intMsg, intMsgLen);
}

char const * die = "CHILD: My DADDY has Killed me!!!\n";
int dieLen;
void sigtstp(int x) {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, die, dieLen);
    exit(111);     // <-- child dies with 111 exit code
}


char const * sigusr1Msg = "SIGUSR1 is being caught\n";
int sigusr1MsgLen;
void sigusr1(int x) {
    write(STDERR_FILENO, sigusr1Msg, sigusr1MsgLen);
}




int main()
{
    dieLen = strlen(die);
    sigusr1MsgLen = strlen(sigusr1Msg);
    hupMsgLen = strlen(hupMsg);
    intMsgLen = strlen(intMsg);

    int         pid;
    sigset_t    allBlockedMask, prevMask, parentUSR1Mask,
                sighupSet, sigintSet, sigtstpSet;

    sigfillset(&sighupSet);
    sigdelset(&sighupSet, SIGHUP);
    sigfillset(&sigintSet);
    sigdelset(&sigintSet, SIGINT);
    sigfillset(&sigtstpSet);
    sigdelset(&sigtstpSet, SIGTSTP);


    sigfillset(&allBlockedMask);

    sigfillset(&parentUSR1Mask);
    sigdelset(&parentUSR1Mask, SIGUSR1);


    struct sigaction saINT, saHUP, saTSTP;
    memset(&saINT, 0, sizeof(saINT));
    memset(&saHUP, 0, sizeof(saHUP));
    memset(&saTSTP, 0, sizeof(saTSTP));
    saINT.sa_flags = 0;
    saINT.sa_handler = sigint;
    saHUP.sa_flags = 0;
    saHUP.sa_handler = sighup;
    saTSTP.sa_flags = 0;
    saTSTP.sa_handler = sigtstp;



    struct sigaction saUSR1;
    memset(&saUSR1, 0, sizeof(saUSR1));
    saUSR1.sa_flags = 0;
    saUSR1.sa_handler = sigusr1;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &saUSR1, 0);



    /* get child process */

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {   /* child */

        fprintf(stderr, "child pid %i\n", getpid());

        /* critical section to set signal handlers */
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &allBlockedMask, &prevMask);
        fprintf(stderr, "child in blocking\n");

        /* set function calls */
        sigaction(SIGHUP, &saHUP, 0);
        sigaction(SIGINT, &saINT, 0);
        sigaction(SIGTSTP, &saTSTP, 0);

        /* let parent know, you can continue your process */
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);

        fprintf(stderr, "child now UNblocked \n");
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prevMask, 0);

        /* here, I want to receive signals in turn */
        sigsuspend(&sighupSet);
        sigsuspend(&sigintSet);
        sigsuspend(&sigtstpSet);


    }
    else {
        /* parent */
        //sleep(2);
        fprintf(stderr, "parent pid %i\n", getpid());


        fprintf(stderr, "parent is waiting\n");
        sigsuspend(&parentUSR1Mask);
        fprintf(stderr, "parent is running\n");


        fprintf(stderr, "\nPARENT: sending SIGHUP\n");
        kill(pid, SIGHUP);

        fprintf(stderr, "\nPARENT: sending SIGINT\n");
        kill(pid, SIGINT);

        fprintf(stderr, "\nPARENT: sending SIGTSTP\n\n");
        kill(pid, SIGTSTP);

        wait(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output when parent runs at first:

```
parent pid 4628
parent is waiting
child pid 4629
child in blocking
child now UNblocked 
SIGUSR1 is being caught
parent is running

PARENT: sending SIGHUP

PARENT: sending SIGINT

PARENT: sending SIGTSTP

CHILD: I have received a SIGHUP
CHILD: My DADDY has Killed me!!!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Sample output when child runs at first:

```
child pid 4657
child in blocking
child now UNblocked 
SIGUSR1 is being caught
parent pid 4656
parent is waiting
.
.
.
```

Comment: `exit()` is not async-signal-safe.  You must not call it from a signal handler.  You may use `_exit()` instead, but sure to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @JohnBollinger < Thank you. AFAIK, `exit()` is like garbage collector, closes file descriptors, deallocate memory blocks before exiting whilst `_exit()` doesn't. _Is there other point I missed?_

Comment: Actually, closing files and releasing memory are two things that you can expect always to happen when a process terminates.  Among the things `exit()` does that `_exit()` does not are to *flush* open streams and to call registered atexit handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

- As mentioned in comments, signal handlers must not call `exit()`, but they may call `_exit()`.
- Your signal handlers do not block signals. This may in fact be responsible for some of your problems, as your signal handlers can themselves be interrupted by signals.  In the "parent runs first" case, for example, the `write()` calls in the child's signal handlers may be interrupted by new signals.  Solve this by using the `sa_mask` members of your `struct sigaction` objects to specify masks of signals to block during execution of your handlers.
- As you have observed, you have a race condition between delivery to the parent of the child's `SIGUSR1` and the parent's call to `sigsuspend()`.  Solve this by blocking all signals in the parent before the fork instead of in the child afterward.  The parent will then not receive the child's `SIGUSR1` until it calls `sigsuspend()` (with a mask that allows it).  The parent can restore the original mask after its `sigsuspend()` returns; the child can continue to restore its signal mask where it now does.

Comment: It works like a charm now. However, I have questions sir. I did `sigemptyset(&saHUP/TSTP/INT.sa_mask);
    sigfillset(&saHUP/TSTP/INT, &saHUP.sa_mask);` which means no signal can interrupt their handlers. Doesn't it? _First question_ is that can handler of a signal be interrupted by own signal? I mean I handle `SIGINT`, when I assert `SIGINT` , its handler is called. Can the handler be interrupted by `SIGINT` (like recursive) ?? _The second one is_ that I can't comprehend logic of calling `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &allBlockedMask, &prevMask);` which blocks all signals before `fork()`? Thank you

Comment: @snr, Signal handlers can be interrupted by signals, including of the same kind they are already handling.  HOWEVER, by default, `sigaction()` registers handlers such that they will not be interrupted by the signals they are already handling.  There is a flag that can be specified to change that.

Comment: As for blocking signals before forking, @snr, I'm not sure what's confusing you.  The problem to be solved was that sometimes the parent received a signal from the child before it was ready.  Blocking it prevents that.  `sigsuspend()` specifies its own signal mask to be used until it returns, which allows it to receive the wanted signal.  Remember always that blocking a signal is completely different from ignoring one.  Blocked signals remain pending, and will be delivered after being unblocked.

Comment: Gotcha after my long breathing-space :) Thank you again.

Comment: Sir sorry for the back but I've encountered a problem additional. If I want to call  `_exit(111)` at the end of child's scope(after `sigsuspend(&sigtstpSet);`) instead of in `SIGTSTP`'s handler(die message printer), the program is being stuck and waits for `SIGINT` and `SIGTSTP` respectively again even though their handlers had called already. _Why cannot I return to child's scope?_

Comment: @snr, it would be best to pose this as a new question.

Comment: I solved the problem sir by movig sigsuspends which are in child process into critical section, after unblocking signals in child's process using `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prevMask, 0);`, signals occurs before going `sigsuspend(&sighupSet);`, So, the situation gives rise to block to parent until child process ends. signals must be sent twice to continue process of child, if not, parent stays in blocking forever.